# Laravel5 ORM : how to alias multiple withCount on the same related object

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a **Hotel** model wich has Many **Rooms** that can be **occupied**. How should I query this :

Hotel list

- the count of Rooms
- the count of Occupied Rooms

The query :

```
$hotels = Hotel::where('foo',$bar)
->withCount('rooms')
->withCount(['rooms' => function ($query) {
    $query->where('status', 'Occupied');
    }])
->get();
```

The result :

`$hotel->rooms_count` gives the count of occupied rooms, which is the last `withCount` expression.

**What I'm tring to get**

- `$hotel->rooms_count`  as the count of rooms in each hotel
- `$hotel->occupied_rooms_count` as the count of occupied rooms of each hotel

as an alias of the second `withcount` :

**Question**

Is there a way to **alias** the second `withCount` on Room ?

Comment: You can simply do a $hotel->occupied_rooms_count = $hotel->rooms_count

Comment: At the moment, the ORM doesn't produce the two fields since they have the same name. The ORM produces only one count.
It's not a simple naming problem

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of specifying `where` clause in your `withCount` define the relation for occupied rooms in `Hotel` Model.

```
public function occupied_rooms(){
    return $this->hasMany(Room::class)
                ->where('status', 'Occupied');
}
```

Now, in your controller use, `withCount('occupied_rooms')`.

```
$hotels = Hotel::where('foo',$bar)
->withCount(['rooms','occupied_rooms'])
->get();
```

Answer (score 26):

Although @jaysingkar's answer is a good way to go and answers the question pretty well, yes, it's possible to alias a `withCount()` call <s>although this hasn't been documented yet</s>:

```
$hotels = Hotel::where('foo', $bar)
    ->withCount([
        'rooms',
        'rooms AS occupied_rooms' => function ($query) {
            $query->where('status', 'Occupied');
        }
    ])
    ->get();
```

This will give you the `$hotel->occupied_rooms_count` with the count of occupied rooms of each hotel. :)

The code where this magic happens [can be seen here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.4/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/QueriesRelationships.php#L165). It was added in Laravel 5.3.7 through the [PR #15279](https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/15279).

**Updated:** I've submitted a PR and it's now [properly documented](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models). :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$hotels = Hotel::where('foo',$bar)
->withCount('rooms AS rooms_count')
->withCount(['rooms AS occupied_rooms_count' => function ($query) {
    $query->where('status', 'Occupied');
    }])
->get();
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit more?